# Why is the `Arr-Disable-Session-Affinity` header coming through on my Azure Web App (WebSite)?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

Following the procedure in [this article](http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2013/11/18/disabling-arrs-instance-affinity-in-windows-azure-web-sites/) I disabled the ARR Affinity cookie on my Azure Web App with this header in my responses:

```
Arr-Disable-Session-Affinity: True
```

It *does* remove the cookie, which is very much a good thing. But, the header itself is still coming through. This header doesn't really hurt anything, but according to that same doc it shouldn't be there:

> If you add the Arr-Disable-Session-Affinity header to disable the affinity cookie, ARR will not set the cookie, but **it will also remove the Arr-Disable-Session-Affinity header itself,** so if your process is working correctly, you will see neither.

So...how do I get it to remove the header, too?

Comment: I am about to ask the same question and found yours.

Comment: I assume things will go wonky without this header value if the app uses in-process state and scaling?

Comment: @TimothyLeeRussell if you use in-proc state then _just don't do anything_. The _default_ behavior has session/server affinity so you should be fine. In my case I _don't want_ affinity so I have to add this header to remove it.

Comment: @MichaelHaren Thanks, that's what I figured. Unfortunately, security scanners don't like the affinity cookie since it isn't httpOnly and doesn't requireSSL.

Comment: One thing that I realized is that the Azure UI does not reflect properly the change, even if you set the variable in the Web.config the properties in the portal says: ON and does not change accordingly

Answer (score 1):

if you have added the **Arr-Disable-Session-Affinity** custom header as below in your Azure Web App web.config, then it is a correct behavior you still see the **Arr-Disable-Session-Affinity** header with value set to true and the ARR cookie removed in your HTTP response. I think it's an incorrect statement in the reference blog you provided which stated that the **Arr-Disable-Session-Affinity** header will be removed.

If you want to remove that header then the cookie will present, it's mutually exclusive.

```
<system.webServer>
<httpProtocol>
  <customHeaders>
    <add name="Arr-Disable-Session-Affinity" value="true" />
  </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The article you refer to doesn't say specifically how to add the header so I can't tell if you did it correctly. I haven't tested but according to [this article](http://blog.mrlacey.co.uk/2013/12/saving-my-users-35mb-in-downloaded-data.html) you should set it in the Application_PreSendRequestHeaders:

```
protected void Application_PreSendRequestHeaders()
{
   Response.Headers.Remove("Server");
   Response.Headers.Remove("X-AspNet-Version");
   Response.Headers.Remove("X-AspNetMvc-Version");
   Response.Headers.Add("Arr-Disable-Session-Affinity", "True");
}
```